# initialize a set with a comparison structure that depends on "this" c++

Tags: c++, stl, initialization, set

I want to define a `set` that does its comparison based on the value of other members of the current class:

```
std::set<ContentType> mySet(doComparison(*this));
```

where doCompare is a struct:

```
struct doCompare{

   doCompare(  MyClass& mc ) : _mc(mc) { }
   MyClass& _mc;

   bool operator()( const ContentType & i1, const ContentType & i2  ){ 
         return _mc.otherMember[i1] < _mc.otherMemeber[i2];
   }

};
```

Here the `mySet` is a member of `MyClass` and when I try to initialize the set with the comparison function in the initialization list: `mySet(doCompare(*this))` the code does not compile.

What am I doing wrong here?

The error is:

```
no matching function for call to ``std::set<ContentType>::set(MyClass::doCompare)`
```

Here is the full message (with the change of names for better readability):

```
./myclass.h:74:165: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<ContentType>::set(MyClass::doCompare)’
 :  mySet(doCompare(*this)) {
                                                                                                ^
./myclass.h:74:165: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:61:0,
                 from ./myclass.h:12,
                 from [blah blah]
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:193:7: note: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = ContentType; _Compare = std::less<ContentType >; _Alloc = std::allocator<ContentType >]
       set(const set& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:193:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass::doCompare’ to ‘const std::set<ContentType >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:180:2: note: template<class _InputIterator> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Compare&, const allocator_type&)
  set(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:180:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from [blahblah]:
./myclass.h:74:165: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
 :  mySet(doCompare(*this)) {
                                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:61:0,
                 from ./myclass.h:12,
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:163:2: note: template<class _InputIterator> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(_InputIterator, _InputIterator)
  set(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:163:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from [blahblah]:
./myclass.h:74:165: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
 : mySet(doCompare(*this)) {
                                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:61:0,
                 from ./myclass.h:12,
                 from blahblah:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:148:7: note: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(const _Compare&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = ContentType; _Compare = std::less<ContentType >; _Alloc = std::allocator<ContentType >; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<ContentType >]
       set(const _Compare& __comp,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:148:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass::doCompare’ to ‘const std::less<ContentType >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:139:7: note: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set() [with _Key = ContentType; _Compare = std::less<ContentType>; _Alloc = std::allocator<ContentType >]
       set()
       ^
```

To summarize the issue:

- It seems I can't initialize the set with the comparison in its declaration, because it depends on **this**.
- The initialization with comparison function after the set is declared is failing, but I don't know why.

**SOLUTION** thanks to  @WhozCraig 
declare mySet as:

```
std::set<ContentType, doCompare> mySet;
```

and initialize it in the initialization list as:

```
mySet(doCompare(*this))
```

Comment: Probably a general lack of `const` correctness.

Comment: I updated the question with the compiler error. The error doesn't seem to be related to `const`s in the definition of `doCompare`. I think something more basic is wrong...

Comment: The problem is, that he wants to use `this` in the initializer list of the constructor. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869281/passing-this-from-constructor-initializer-list

Comment: @Siamak Can you post the full error with all related information?

Comment: Is there a reason you're *not* declaring your set with the optional comparator type template parameter before attempting all of this: ?  `std::set<ContentType,doCompare>`

Comment: That doesn't compile either. It gives an error that says **this** is non-static etc. The issue is that I'm passing **this** to the comparison function

Comment: I think you should declare your comparator as a template parameter when declaring your set :std::set<ContentType, docompare>. You should also include you compiler errors in your post

Comment: see my answer to @WhozCraig, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Siamak perhaps I didn't understand your response, or you didn't understand my question. `std::set` accepts as a second template parameter a *type* for comparison (not a function; though you could use a function type, but you're not). Without specifying that type `std::less<T>` is the default. The comparator *object* (its not a function, its a *functor*) you're passing in the constructor does not match `std::less<T>`, nor does it match any other `std::set<ContentType>` alternate constructor parameter list. Thus your error "No matching function". [See it live](https://ideone.com/ohROEG)

Comment: I guess you're right, but what is the solution? Declaration of `std::set<ContentType,doCompare(*this)>' fails to compile as well.

Comment: Look again at the posted live sample. and look back at my first comment. that decl should be `std::set<ContentType,doCompare>`, note the second argument. there is no`this` involved (not yet; that comes later on the `MyClass` constructor initializer list). Unrelated (slightly), I believe it highly likely you should make the `doCompare::_mc` reference member const as well. I see no reason for it to be hot.

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood you first comment. Yes, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not declaring your set type with the proper template comparator parameter. This:

```
std::set<ContentType> mySet;
```

means this when expanded:

```
std::set<ContentType, std::less<ContentType>> mySet
```

leaving out the allocator for brevity. This means when constructing `mySet` and specifying an alternate comparator functor, it must be of type `std::less<ContentType>`, but yours is not. It is of type `doCompare`. The compiler tries to match against every other constructor argument list, failing to find any match, finally resulting in your error.

Change your declaration of `mySet` to:

```
std::set<ContentType,doCompare> mySet;
```

Now the types should wire up correctly.

And as I said in comments, i see no reason the reference to your `MyClass` being held in your comparator object should be non-const. unless you can think of a good reason, I suggest changing the reference to const instead, i.e. `const MyClass&`